# Change AMSlider menu option on button click

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, amslidemenu

I am trying to implement AMSlide menu in iOS8 withoutStoryboard.

I have used left-menu in two different tables.

1. leftmenuTVC
2. AfterloginleftMenuTVC So Slider-->>loginVC

If login button is pressed I would like to open new Slider `Afterloginleftmenu`.

LoginVC

```
-(IBAction)clicklogin:(id)sender {
    [[Singleton sharedInstance]setLoginshared:@"YES"];
    [self.mainSlideMenu openLeftMenu];
}
```

MainVC

```
-(void) Viewload {
    if ([StoreData isEqualToString:@"NO"]) {
         self.leftMenu = [[LeftMenuTVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"LeftMenuTVC" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.leftMenu = [[AfterloginleftMenuTVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"AfterloginleftMenuTVC" bundle:nil];
    }
}
```